# Empty Array that Still Has Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, cordova

After pushing multiple elements into an array and logging it, Chrome DevTools is telling me that it's empty. However, the console still its displays elements.

Here's a picture that describes what I'm saying: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMv1y.jpg.

The first displayed array is the atypical array and the second array is just a normal array that I logged for comparison.

I'm at a complete loss as to what is happening here. How can I have an empty array with elements still inside of it? And why does the console say that the array has a length of 7 when it's empty.

If it makes any difference I'm using Cordova and the DevTools is on a page with Ripple.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you log the array when it's empty. The console shows the *live* state of the object.

[image]